# How to define functions inside an array in C?

Tags: c

There's anyway to define functions inside an array in C? I don't want to create all those functions because it will polute my code and there's no need for this. I was thinking something like this:

`double (q[1])(X[2])={(double X[2]){return X[0]}};`

but it seems not right way to do that.

I will be clear, i have alot of derivatives, but i now their formula and it will be used in few places in my code, so, if i create a function to each derivative would make my code unreadble, the best solution would be create them inside a vector, and call them as a array of functions.

Comment: It is not what i want, i would need to declare those functions in my code and put them into an array. I wish to declare them inside an array without need to create in another place.

Comment: You won’t be able to do so. The closest thing you can do is to use function pointers. The function would have to be declared elsewhere.

Comment: C does not work that way.

Comment: I don't even understand what `functions inside an array` mean and what you want with that weird syntax. Array elements store data and not code. It can store function pointers though. If you have a lot of similar function implementations then use a macro instead